# When should we detachStream from DataWriter and DataReader? And what's the general guideline of this I/O model?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-10-universal

Implement using C++/CX.
From the DataReaderWriter sample, it says we should detachStream() before the DataWriter object die in order to keep the stream from being closed. But in other DataWriter/DataReader sample codes, I didn't find more evidence which suggest this is a requirement, and the docs don't mention anything more details. My question is, when should we detachStream()?  For example, if a StreamSocket object outlive the DataWriter object, do I have to detachStream()?
Or is this only required when there is no other references holding the life of the underlying stream object?

And one more question about DataWriter/DataReader:
After we call StoreAsync/LoadAsync in thread A, can we continue call WriteXXX/ReadXXX in thread A without block waiting for the Store/Load complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, when should we detachStream()?

As the [comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DataReaderWriter/cpp/Scenario1_WriteReadStream.xaml.cpp#L101) in DataReaderWriter sample said:

> In order to prolong the lifetime of the stream, detach it from the DataWriter so that it will not be closed when the dataWriter is destructed. Were we to fail to detach the stream, the dataWriter destructor would close the underlying stream, preventing its subsequent use by the DataReader below.

The [`DetachStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.detachstream.aspx) method is used here because the underlying stream need to be used by the subsequent `DataReader`. If we don't detach it from the `DataWriter`, it will be closed when the `dataWriter` is destructed. So this method is not a requirement. It depends on your scenario, if you don't need to use the stream after you close `DataWriter`, you can do not use this method.

For StreamSocket, if you want to reuse the socket with another data writer, you must detach the stream from the current writer before disposing it. So in a sense, if a `StreamSocket` object outlive the `DataWriter` object, you should use `DetachStream` method.

> After we call StoreAsync/LoadAsync in thread A, can we continue call WriteXXX/ReadXXX in thread A without block waiting for the Store/Load complete?

I'm not sure why you want to continue to call WriteXXX/ReadXXX without waiting for the Store/Load complete. For [`StoreAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.storeasync.aspx) method, it commits data in the buffer to a backing store. We usually use it when we finished writing data. So when we call this method there should be no other call of WriteXXX method. And for [`LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.loadasync.aspx) method, we need to wait for it to complete before calling ReadXXX method in case of the data is not loaded completely or the data load operation fails.

Comment: Thanks, I've got further and other questions on the usage of the I/O model of Windows Runtime. I'd like to concentrate the discussion on msdn, can you give me further suggestions there? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/621ec441-3597-4a60-b2b8-8de62f0c608a/uwpcserveral-questions-about-datawriterdatareader-and-the-associated-io-model?forum=wpdevelop   and   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8dcdbfcf-72e2-4d71-b26b-f40432316c5f/uwpcwhich-design-is-better-producerconsumer-with-concurrency-runtime-or-block-wait-for-async?forum=wpdevelop